# Duplicate identifier 'Asset'. webpack: failed to compile error while ng serve angular-app(generated from hyperledger-composer:angular)

Tags: angularjs, webpack, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, yo

I used `yo hyperledger-composer:angular` to create skeleton app. when I cd into the app directory and performed ng serve, I got the following error(please refer to the image).

I used both `npm install` and `ng serve`. But both resulted in the same error:

ERROR in /Users/swaroop/angular-app/src/app/test.ts (1,9): Duplicate identifier 'Asset'.

ERROR in /Users/swaroop/angular-app/src/app/test.ts (5,9): Duplicate identifier 'Asset'.
webpack: Failed to compile.

**Screenshot:**
[image: output error]

Comment: what is your OS and operating system version?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in code generation.

Below is the solution:

Go to [path_to_angular_app]/src/app/test.ts and comment the below statement

//import {Asset} from './org.hyperledger.composer.system';

Save it and go back to your terminal and run the below commands, or close and open a new terminal.

sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:4200)

ng serve

** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
 47% building modules 313/325 modules 12 active ...s/html-entities/lib/html5-entities.jswebpack: wait until bundle finished: /

webpack: Compiled successfully.